# Disable most recently used items in Subgrid lookup controls

Tags: dynamics-365, powerapps-modeldriven

I have to disable or remove the most recently used items in Subgrid lookup (refer to the screenshot-1). How this can be done? thank you, Siva
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BguAV.png)

Our clients click "Add Existing" button from the Subgrid and try to select value from "Recent records" list instead of selecting from Subgrid lookup. That's why, the "Recent records " entry should be hiden to ensure users make the selection from the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this JS code on Onload event of your form:

```
 function cacherElementsRecemmentUtilises() {
    var regleCss = '';
    try {
    regleCss += 'ul[aria-label="recent records"] {display:none!important} ';
    regleCss += 'ul[aria-label="Enregistrements récents"]{display:none!important} ';
    var styleElement = parent.document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(regleCss));
    parent.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
        
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.Message);
    }
    
}
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).